# How to deploy next.js app to Gitlab / Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a `pages/index.js` which is available at `localhost:3000` when I run locally `next`.

I want to run `next build && next export` and deploy this page to Gitlab Pages. Due to how Gitlab Pages (or Github Pages for that matter) work, my page should be accessible to `https://my-username.gitlab.io/my-nextjs-project/`. But because of this segment `/my-nextjs-project/` that appears in the URL, I wasn't able to successfully deploy my app to Gitlab Pages.

If this would be a simple React app, I would set the `output.publicPath` in `webpack.config.js`. What's the analog of `output.publicPath` in next.js? Or, do you know a public project deployed to Gitlab/Github Pages so I can check their configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file that you are using to deploy your app to Gitlab Pages?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. If it's still relevant for you, this is the part from .gitlab-ci.yml used to deploy to Gitlab Pages (but finally I end up deploying to Heroku because of the issue described in my question above): `pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run -i --rm -v $PWD/public:/usr/src/app/build $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE yarn run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master`

Answer (score 3):

On your next.config.js add assetPrefix. Setting it up to assetPrefix: 'test' will put everything under test

```
module.exports = {
  // some configuration
  assetPrefix: isProduction ? '/{reponame}' : '',
  // another configuration
}
```

Hope this helps, here is a link from Next.js on how to deploy it to GitHub pages. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Deploying-a-Next.js-app-into-GitHub-Pages

Comment: Thanks @ArnavBorborah I believe I corrected my answer based on your feedback

Comment: @Abel_Alvarez The link is dead. Is there another reference?

Comment: Did you try adding `assetPrefix` on your `next.config.js`?